# Disassembling MIPS 32 version 1 binary with the Radare2 Framework

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, elf, radare2, mips

I am trying to disassemble a MIPS 32 version 1 binary with the Radare2 framework.

Here is the full output of the `file` command:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, stripped
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, make sure you run the latest version of radare2 from git repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2.git
$ cd radare2
$ ./sys/install.sh
```

If you don’t want to install the git version or you want the binaries for another machine (Windows, OS X, iOS, etc) check out the [download page](http://radare.org/r/down.html) at the radare2 website.

To open `MIPS` binary with radare2, simply use the following command:

```
radare2 -a mips -b 32 ./file
```

- `-a` arch - set asm.arch (x86, ppc, arm, mips, bf, java, ...)
- `-b` bits - set asm.bits (16, 32, 64)

Don't forget to read the manual (`man r2`), it's all there.

For more relative information you can watch Andrew McDonnell's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3sGlzXfEkU) 
 called "*Reverse engineering embedded software using radare2*" (slides: [link](http://rada.re/get/r2embed-auckland2015.pdf)).

If you feel that you need more basic information about radare2 and how to use it, I recommend the following sources:

1. [Radare2 Book](https://www.gitbook.com/book/radare/radare2book/details)
2. [Radare2 Explorations](https://www.gitbook.com/book/monosource/radare2-explorations/details)
3. [Radare Demystified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnpBy3wWabA) (Talk)

Comment: Thanks for the response Megabeets but my system can run MIPS code and I don't have qemu installed. Wouldn't that command (radare2 -a mips -b 32 ./file) try to run the file because of the ./?

Comment: The command will not execute the file. In order to execute the file (i.e open it in debug mode) you need to pass the `-d` flag to radare. The command mentioned before will open the binary in read-only mode and will help you to conduct static analysis. The prepended "./" just means that the file is in the current folder. You can avoid it and simply call it with `r2 -a mips -b 32 filename`